# Using R to find out repetition in data

Tags: r, statistics

Let's say I have a table with thousands of values (time, value). When I plot them, I can see that the values are "kind of" repetitive (all 24 hours the values roughly repeat).

But there is an clearly visible attack time at the beginning. How can I find out, at which time the repetition is 100% the same (or even 99%) using R?

(For example: after three days, all following cycles are 99% identically)

Comment: welcome to SO! please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help with your issues. Using dput(head(data, 20)). Also the output of what you're looking for

Comment: @Matt W. The ops username was ironic when i read your post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean some of your rows are duplicates. In which case:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

This is a common question. You can find an answer faster by searching other questions on the same topic on SO. Good luck learning R.